# COUNT multiple types of same column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

In my current query:

```
SELECT COUNT(WC.ID) AS "Regions" 
FROM WHOLE_FEATURES_PDB_CHAINS AS WC 
;
```

I `COUNT(WC.ID) AS "Regions"` . 
However, we have multiple regions with WC.Type can be `1,2,3,4`. I need to count each type occurrence into `COUNT(WC.ID) AS "Region_1"`, `COUNT(WC.ID) AS "Region_2"` ... depending on `WC.Type`. 
Is there any way to solve this in one query? I am looking at MySQL `IF`, yet do not know how to integrate it into the count function.

I need it to be in one row (the shown query here is reduced, it's a larger query)

```
SELECT COUNT(WC.ID) AS "Region_1" , COUNT(WC.ID) AS "Region_2" ...
```

Here is the complete query if anyone is interested:

```
SELECT PCS.PDB_id, PCS.Chain, PPA.ENSEMBL_start, PPA.ENSEMBL_end, PPA.eValue, PIN.TITLE AS "pdbTitle", COUNT(WC.ID) AS "Regions" 
FROM PDB_Chains AS PCS 
LEFT JOIN WHOLE_FEATURES_PDB_CHAINS AS WC ON WC.PDB_CHAIN_ID = PCS.idPDB_chains, PDB_protein_alignment PPA, PDB_INFOS PIN 
WHERE PCS.idPDB_chains = PPA.idPDB_Chains 
AND PCS.PDB_id = PIN.PDB_ID 
AND PPA.idProteins = (SELECT idProteins from Proteins WHERE ENSEMBL_protein_id = "'+submittedID+'") 
GROUP BY PCS.PDB_id, PCS.Chain ORDER BY PCS.PDB_id;
```

---

Here's the working solutin based on your kind answers

```
SELECT PIN.TITLE AS "pdbTitle", COUNT(CASE WHEN WC.STRUCTURAL_FEATURES_ID = 1 then 1 end) AS "PPInterface" , COUNT(CASE WHEN WC.STRUCTURAL_FEATURES_ID = 4 then 1 end) AS "flexibleRegions" 
FROM PDB_Chains AS PCS LEFT JOIN WHOLE_FEATURES_PDB_CHAINS AS WC ON WC.PDB_CHAIN_ID = PCS.idPDB_chains, PDB_protein_alignment PPA, PDB_INFOS PIN 
WHERE PCS.idPDB_chains = PPA.idPDB_Chains 
AND PCS.PDB_id = PIN.PDB_ID 
AND PPA.idProteins = (SELECT idProteins from Proteins WHERE ENSEMBL_protein_id = "ENSP00000256078.4") 
GROUP BY PCS.PDB_id, PCS.Chain ORDER BY PCS.PDB_id;
```

Comment: Use count(case when WC.type = 1 then 1 end) as region_1, similarly repeat for another column.

Comment: Thanks @FahadAjun , that works... :D

Comment: Can I post it as an answer ?

Comment: Certainly, I was already thinking you were missing out on the fame :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use case when statement inside your aggregate function.

Try this .

count(case when WC.type = 1 then 1 end) as region_1, similarly repeat for another column.

Comment: Or, more tersely, `SUM(WC.type = 1) AS region_1` since a boolean sums as 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
...
...
sum(if WC.ID = 1 then 1 else 0) as Region1,
sum(if WC.ID = 2 then 1 else 0) as Region2,
sum(if WC.ID = 3 then 1 else 0) as Region3,
sum(if WC.ID = 4 then 1 else 0) as Region4
```

Might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` with `COUNT` to get the required result, e.g.:

```
SELECT WC.Type, COUNT(WC.ID) AS "Regions" 
FROM WHOLE_FEATURES_PDB_CHAINS AS WC 
GROUP BY WC.Type;
```

**Update**

If you want the counts as pivoted column for each region then you can write inner `SELECT` queries, e.g.:

```
SELECT
 (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM WHOLE_FEATURES_PDB_CHAINS WHERE type = 1) AS "Region_1",
 (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM WHOLE_FEATURES_PDB_CHAINS WHERE type = 2) AS "Region_2",
other_column
FROM WHOLE_FEATURES_PDB_CHAINS AS WC
WHERE <some condition>;
```

Comment: Thank you, but I added an edit to specify it has to be in one row. Your suggestion would work if it was only for that.

Comment: Can I then condition to a overall subset that would apply to the above subqueries? `WHERE WC.ID = PDB.hasWholeRegionID` ? I do not need the full count of the table, only a subset in the table, hence the required `WHERE`...

Comment: You can't condition the overall subset but you can add the above condition into each query with `AND`.

Comment: @ElDude You want to use condition in where so that you will get the result only for that WC.ID ?